# powershell Invoke-Sqlcmd doesn't write error to output file

Tags: powershell

I use the following powershill script

```
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100

$lines = Get-Content _lists.txt
$stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "_error.txt"
$stream.Open();
ForEach ($line in $lines)
{
try {

        $out = "_temp"+$line.split(".")[0] + ".txt" ;
        Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile $line -ServerInstance "localhost" | Format-Table | Out-File -FilePath $out 
        if(!$?) 
        {
            $stream.WriteLine($out);

        }
    } 
    catch {
          "error when running sql $sql"
          Write-Host($error)
    }
    finally
    {

    }
}
$stream.Close();
```

but the outputfile always empty , and  the output appear on the command line , any idea to write it properly

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "ErrorVariable" [common parameter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315352.aspx) when calling Invoke-SqlCmd. That parameter requires defining a variable that will potentially contain the error message. It will also be stored in the $error array.

Note that the variable name is NOT prefixed by a $ in the invocation ...

```
$sqlErr = $null
Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstance -Database $database -Query $query -ErrorVariable sqlErr -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
if ($sqlErr) 
{ 
    #Something went wrong ...
}
```